# could not get connection factory client error and i can not see map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Hi here i am trying to load my location in map but i just get blank canvas.

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.exmp.way"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"  />
<uses-permission android:name="com.way.fameceramic.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"  />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.exmp.way.MapActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity></application> </manifest>
```

this is mainfest code

here Layout file code

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

for security reason i disable key

MapActivity Code here

```
import java.util.List;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MapViewActivity extends MapActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_view);

       // Displaying Zooming controls
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    /**
     * Changing Map Type
     * */
    // mapView.setSatellite(true); // Satellite View
    // mapView.setStreetView(true); // Street View
    mapView.setTraffic(true); // Traffic view

    /**
     * showing location by Latitude and Longitude
     * */        
    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    double lat = Double.parseDouble("22.270928");
    double lon = Double.parseDouble("70.789909");
    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon * 1E6));
    mc.animateTo(geoPoint);
    mc.setZoom(15);
    mapView.invalidate(); 


    /**
     * Placing Marker
     * */
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);
    AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = 
         new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);


    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, "Fame Ceramic", "Way web Solution");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;

    }



}
```

AddItemizedOverlay  class source here

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class AddItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {


   private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

   private Context context;

   public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
   }

   public AddItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        this(defaultMarker);
        this.context = context;
   }

   @Override
   protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return mapOverlays.get(i);
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
      return mapOverlays.size();
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      Log.e("Tap", "Tap Performed");
      return true;
   }

   public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
      mapOverlays.add(overlay);
       this.populate();
   }

   /**
    * Getting Latitude and Longitude on Touch event
    * **/
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
   {   

       if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
           GeoPoint geopoint = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
               (int) event.getX(),
               (int) event.getY());
           // latitude
           double lat = geopoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6;
           // longitude
           double lon = geopoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6;
           Toast.makeText(context, "Lat: " + lat + ", Lon: "+lon, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }                            
       return false;
   } 

}
```

Here i past all code i used.... give me solution where am i wrong 
i just got this[image]

Comment: When you open Google Maps, do you see more information? It seems like your problem is that your device isn't actually downloading the maps from Google.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/. Follow the steps in the link

Answer (score 0):

You need a "google programmer account", for to get it, maybe it is.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed Android Maps API v1 and v2. Remove all the code and follow this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

You don't want things like `MapActivity` and `GeoPoint` in your code anymore.